# How to Create a channel integration like Shopify in my courier company portal?

Tags: php, shopify, integration, channel

In a courier company I want to integrate different Channel like Shopify in the portal so that the order from Shopify will be list in the portal and then they can ship the product from the portal.
It is like shiprocket or nimbus which integrate channel. How can I able to achive this ?

Answer (score 1):

The usual approach would be for you to provide what Shopify calls a fulfillment service in the merchant store. If you are a fulfillment service, then the merchant can choose to fulfill line items sold in orders with your service. You would then be able to provide fulfillment information like tracking numbers etc.

But it gets complicated pretty fast. Your involvement with Shopify to master being a selectable courier can also be done via becoming a delivery option in the merchant's shipping selections. Again, for that to be a reality you have some complicated work. Not easy.

Comment: Now I just want to list order of Shopify in my portal and then ship it from there. So which process will be reliable calling orders from api or creating orders through webhook.

Comment: Sorry. I do not understand your question. You want Shopify orders to show up in your portal? You would need to install an App in the Shopify store, and then that App could easily provide orders to your portal.

Comment: Yes I know it that from app I can do that but the problem is that in my portal multiple users login and enter there Shopify api details and the orders should be displayed which they can ship from the portal . But the problem is that I want to know that how the courier company like ship rocket , delhivery integrate Shopify channel through the app api or through the webhook on order create .